# Doctrine Pagination In codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, doctrine-orm, pagination

I'm new to doctrine and using doctrine for my CI application. It's nice so far but I've stuck with pagination. The Paginator class returns the object but when I try to get the count I get the following error.

```
//_clone method called on non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\globalauto\application\libraries\Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator.php
```

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

```
public function getAllLogisitics()
{
    $logisticsMeta = new LogisticsMeta();
    $logisticEntity = $this->em->getRepository('models\Entities\Logistics');
    $query =$this->em->createQuery('SELECT * FROM logistics')->setFirstResult(0)
                   ->setMaxResults(10);
    $paginator = new Paginator($query, false);
    $c = count($paginator);//get error on this line
    foreach ($paginator as $logistic) {
        echo $logistic->getStatus() . "\n";
    }
}
```

Here's What I've tried from doctrine page

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/pagination.html

I used doctrine version 2.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it through CI pagination.

```
public function getAllLogisitics($limit, $start)
{
    $data = array();
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    $this->db->order_by('id', 'desc');
    $logisticsList = $this->db->get("logistics");
    $logistics_data = array();
    $logistic = $this->em->getRepository('models\Entities\Logistics');
    foreach ($logisticsList->result_array() as $logistics) {
        $logisticsObj = $logistic->findby(array("id" => $logistics["id"]));
        $logisticsTemp['Logistics'] = $logisticsObj;
        $logisticsTemp['LogisticsMeta'] = $this->functions->getMeta('models\Entities\LogisticsMeta', 'logistics', $logistics["id"]);
        $logistics_data[] = $logisticsTemp;
    }
    return $logistics_data;
}
```